# Kubernetes Service not being assigned an (external) IP address

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

There are various answers for very similar questions around SO that all show what I *expect* my deployment to look like, however mine does not.

- I am running Minikube 0.25, with Kubernetes 1.9 on Windows
  10.
- I have successfully created a node, a replication controller, and a
  single pod template has been replicated 10 times.
- The node is Minikube, and is assigned the IP address 10.49.106.251
- The dashboard is available at 10.49.106.251:30000

I am deploying a service with a YAML file, but the service is never assigned an external IP - the result is the same if I happen to use `kubectl expose`.

The YAML file that I am using:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: hello-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: hello-world
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 8080
```

I can also use the YAML file to assign an external IP - I assign it the same value as the node IP address. Either way results in no possible connection to the service. I should also point out that the 10 replicated pods all match the selector.

The result of running `kubectl get svc` for the default, and after updating the external IP are below:

```
NAME            TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)          AGE
hello-service   NodePort    10.108.61.233   <none>          8080:32406/TCP   1m
hello-service   NodePort    10.108.61.233   10.49.106.251   8080:32406/TCP   1m
```

The tutorial I have been following, and the other answers on SO show a result similar to:

```
hello-service   NodePort    10.108.61.233   <nodes>   8080:32406/TCP   1m
```

Where the difference is that the external IP is set to <nodes>

I have encountered a number of issues when running locally - is this just another case of doing so, or has someone else identified a way to get around the external IP assignment issue?

Comment: Which tutorial were you following? Can you please share the link?

Comment: did you fix this issue? I am also facing same.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I actually just moved on to something else and avoided k8s...

Answer (score 4):

For local development purpose, I have also met with the problem of exposing a 'public IP' for my local development cluster.
Fortunately, I have found one of the kubectl command which can help:

```
kubectl port-forward service/service-name 9092
```

Where 9092 is the container port to expose, so that I can access applications inside the cluster, on my local development environment.

The important note is that it is not a 'production' grade solution.
Works well as a temporary hack to get to the cluster insides.

Answer (score 2):

Using NodePort means it will open a port on all nodes of your cluster.  In your example above, the port exposed to the outside world is 32406.
In order to access hello-service (if it is http) it will be http://[ the node ip]:32406/.  This will hit your minikube and the the request will be routed to your pod in roundrobin fashion.

Comment: Yup, that is what it SHOULD be doing, but it is not. It's not accessible on that port on the node IP. You can see this in the lines I posted above... The service is also correctly mapped to the appropriate internal ports.

Comment: Can you post your deployment manifest? Most often the deployment labels does not match the service selectors.  I got bitten by this a couple of times.

Comment: This isn't an issue - I can go into the dashboard and see the pods sitting under the service correctly, which means the labels have matched up.

Comment: @BaltazarChua Your comment helped me save a few hours. You'd think kubernetes would provide a error/warning for such schema less yaml files.

Answer (score 1):

same problem when trying to deploy a simple helloworld image locally with **Kubernetes v1.9.2** 
After two weeks of attempts , It seems that Kubernetes expose all **nginx web server** applications internally in port `80` not `8080` 
So this should work `kubectl expose deployment hello-service --type=NodePort --port=80`